# When creating a jQuery plugin, should `this` always be the native DOM element in any callbacks?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, waitforimages

I've written a [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages), and I recently made it so the callback has access to `this`, which is the original selector, so you can do...

```
$('#something').waitForImages(function() {
   $(this).fadeIn(500);
});
```

This looks very much like some code you'd expect in the jQuery API.

However, jQuery always provides `this` as the native DOM element, so you must wrap it with `$()` to start calling jQuery's methods on it.

[Originally](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages/commit/1d0c591974a2634a0599b1599ce635e15eaaf08f#L2R32), I provided `this` as a jQuery object. But then, after observing jQuery's handling of `this`, [I changed it](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages/commit/11d75df0fcdb645984eb9cb04834b26b610d490c#L0R49).

What is the best way? To provide it wrapped or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say leave it *unwrapped* in this situation, since this appears to be an event handler.  In an event handler almost *always* (in jQuery *and* in raw JS event handlers) you expect `this` to be the **DOM element** you're dealing with...that's the convention I'd stick with.

Generally, try to go with the principle of least surprise when you can.

If you want, you could also passed the wrapped element as a parameter to the function, for example:

```
$('#something').waitForImages(function(e, jQueryObjectHere) {
   $(this).fadeIn(500);
});
```

...that way you aren't doing something unexpected, but provide the goodies if they're wanted.  I wouldn't by any means say this is *necessary*, just handy.  The above is just an option (random thought really)...though if you exposed this event as something you can [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to, *don't* do this, since they may be binding additional data and expect that.

Answer (score 2):

The raw DOM element is what people will expect if you write your plugin.  You may feel changing this is more convenient and readable, but it is not standard and if you plan on distributing it to the open source community it will only cause confusion and duplication of jQuery objects.  `$(this)` when `this` refers t a preexisting jQuery collection will not error out, but will most definitely not be efficient.

Your code will iterate over the collection and execute the callback for any elements anyways, so you can think of each callback unique to a single element in the collection, not as being executed once on the entire collection as a whole.

Hope this explains the rational and "high-level" vision as to the design choice.  It boils down to semantics and consistency.

Answer (score 1):

Many times when I write a jQuery plugin I will immediately assign `this` to a variable like so:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function () {
  var $this = this;
};
```

The main reason is so that I can refer to the original selector within an interior function that redefines `this`, but the reason that's more relevant here is that `this` on it's own looks like an unwrapped DOM element so the $ in front of `$this` helps me remember that it's already wrapped.

Therefore, I think that you should indeed provide `this` as a DOM element and let users wrap it in `$()` if they wish to.

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the array of selected elements that was returned by the jQuery function. Rewrapping the elements is highly unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this really answers my question.

Comment: How so? You asked if you should rewrap it, and I said no.

Comment: This isn't in a plugin, this is an event call for *for* a plugin, for example `this` is a DOM element inside a `.click()` handler, that's more akin to this situation.

Comment: Before your edit, and the time I left the comment, your answer was *`this` refers to the array of selected elements*, which didn't answer the question. I can see you have updated it now though :)